# Image List with Next and Previous Button in Windows Form

Tags: c#, facebook-c#-sdk

I am working on a Windows form. I get some images from a directory in images box with ArrayList. I load images successfully and also images show with next and previous buttons. Now I also wanna get the image URL when the image changes with buttons. I tried but unsuccessfully, here is my code:

```
ArrayList arylist = new ArrayList();
        int i = 0;
        int filelength = 0;
        //Initially load all your image files into the array list when form 
  load first time
        System.IO.DirectoryInfo inputDir = new DirectoryInfo("E:\\BD 
  Images");//Images Folder path
        try
        {
            if (inputDir.Exists)
            {
                ////Get Each file
                System.IO.FileInfo file = null;
                foreach(System.IO.FileInfo eachfile in inputDir.GetFiles())
                {
                    file = eachfile;
                    if(file.Extension == ".jpg")
                    {
                        arylist.Add(file.FullName);//add files in array list
                        filelength = filelength + 1;
                    }
                }
                BDpictureBox.Image = 
    Image.FromFile(arylist[0].ToString());//Display intially first image in 
    picture box as sero index file path
                ImageUrltextBox.Text = file.FullName;//This line show the 
    url in text box
                i = 0;
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error"+ex);
        }

private void NextImagebutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {           
        if (i + 1 < filelength)
        {
            BDpictureBox.Image = Image.FromFile(arylist[i + 1].ToString());
            ImageUrltextBox.Text = file.FullName;
            i = i + 1;

        }
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by the "image URL" ? Why would a .jpg file have a URL?

Comment: If you mean "FullName" isn't it just this `arylist[i + 1].ToString()` ?

Comment: i wanna show image url in text box  this line show the url of first image in text box ImageUrltextBox.Text = file.FullName

Comment: If you want the file "Path" then get it out of the array list, not from the variable that you overwrite in a loop.

Comment: Thanks its working (y)